# Shortening my IF statement containing both: & and ||

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
if(whats.above(x,y)=="g" && whats.onLeft(x,y)=="g") {
    $(this).css("border-top-color","green").css("border-left-color","green");
}
```

`whats.above` and `whats.onLeft` can return some letters. In this case, my statement checks if it's going to return `g` in both cases.

However, I have more letters now, and I want this statement to be `true` for more of them. Here, there's only one letter, `g`, but I want some others, for example `n`. I know I cannot do something like this:

```
if(whats.above(x,y)==("g"||"n"))
```

**What can I do to minimalize my code in this case?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) with a string with the letters.

```
if ('gn'.indexOf(whats.above(x,y)) !== -1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, The problem is in your statement is it should be

```
if(whats.above(x,y)=="g"|| whats.above(x,y) == "n"){    }
```

For a better solution, I would go with

```
if (["g","n"].indexOf(whats.above(x,y)) > -1){    }
```

Comment: I need both, `whats.above` and `whats.onLeft` return `g` or `n` in my statement. My statement is correct and I need to **extend** it. Although, `indexOf();` helped me out here, thanks!